# shadow DOM encapsulating javascript like an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I'm trying to figure out if the Javascript executed in a Shadow DOM can be scoped (like what the [sandbox property of an iframe tag does](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)). I don't want the Javascript loaded to mess with the rest of the page content, or event have access to properties such as `window.open` that could eventually end up opening tabs everywhere.

It would be of a great help if anyone has an example of a procedure to do so.
thanks,

Comment: No, that is not part of what shadow DOM does (and even if it did, you should never execute untrusted code "that could eventually end up opening tabs everywhere").

Comment: arf. Thanks Jordan. I keep the question open in case that changes in futur versions.

Comment: put a sandboxed iframe in your shadow dom...